# Display icon to indicate that a cell has a dropdown/list attached to it

Tags: javascript, css, tabulator

When using list editors to select values from a dropdown menu, I would like the unedited cell to have an icon that shows that it has a list attached.

Something that looks like the standard html select input e.g.

London    V

Rather than the current behaviour where they appear the same as a text input.

e.g. on the Location and Gender cells in the editable example

https://tabulator.info/examples/5.5#editable

Is there a simple way to achieve this through css styling?

I have looked at the elements that make up the table cells, but could not figure out what would need to be added to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a td and give it a class like 'editable' `<td class="editable">` you could apply CSS to that. My first thought is something like `td.editable::after {...}` where you could use an image or a character (unicode U+25bc down pointing triangle) and use positioning to move it into the table cell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I should have made it clearer that this relates to the tabulator.js javascript table library.

Answer (score 0):

On way would be to use [custom cell formatter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/format#format-custom) to change how a cell element is displayed.  Here is an example where I added down arrows to the color column with list editor:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' },
]

const table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: data,
  height: '300px',
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age' },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    {
      title: 'Favourite Color',
      field: 'col',
      formatter: (cell) => cell.getValue() + '<span class="listArrow"></span>',
      editor: 'list',
      editorParams: {
        values: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'],
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

```css
.listArrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  border: solid #333333;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.